# Property of category class set in swizzled class method always returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, objective-c-category, swizzling

I wanted to create a category of UIImage class which will have its own handling of

```
(UIImage*) imageNamed:(NSString*) name
```

method which will save for me the name as a property of created image. In order to do so, I created a swizzle for this method and associated references to my newly added property for its setters and getters. In the end the implementation looks like this:

```
@interface UIImage (MTReady)

@property(assign) NSString* imageName;

-(NSString*) getImageName;

@end

NSString * const imageNameKey = @"imageNameKey";

@implementation UIImage (MTReady)
@dynamic imageName;

-(NSString *)getImageName {
    NSString* name = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey);
    return name;
}

-(void) setImageName:(NSString *)name {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

+(void)load {
    if(self == [UIImage class]) {
        Method originalImageNamed, swizzledImageNamed;

        originalImageNamed = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamed:));
        swizzledImageNamed = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(swizzledImageNamed:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalImageNamed, swizzledImageNamed);
    }
}

+(UIImage *)swizzledImageNamed:(NSString*) name {
    UIImage* image = [self swizzledImageNamed:name];

    if(image)
        [image setImageName:name];
    return image;
}

@end
```

This solution does not seem to work since whenever I call *getImageName* on an UIImage which was created using method *imageNamed* I always get *nil*. I am currently out of ideas why does it happen. Is there something I am missing from my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
```

should be

```
 objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
```

or

```
 objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
```

Don't use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` or `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` as the string might be mutable. Exactly the same reason the you declare string properties as copy rather than strong.

When I test the below code the associated is set and retrieved correctly.

```
@implementation UIImage (Name)

static char const imageNameKey;

-(NSString *)getImageName {
  NSString* name = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey);
  return name;
}

-(void) setImageName:(NSString *)name {
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

+(void)load {
  if(self == [UIImage class]) {
    Method originalImageNamed, swizzledImageNamed;

    originalImageNamed = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamed:));
    swizzledImageNamed = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(swizzledImageNamed:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalImageNamed, swizzledImageNamed);
 }
}

+(UIImage *)swizzledImageNamed:(NSString*) name {
  UIImage* image = [self swizzledImageNamed:name];

  if(image)
    [image setImageName:name];
  return image;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is this a typo? I don't think `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_COPY` is  a thing.

Comment: Good spot, I meant `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.

Comment: It still keeps returning *nil* whenever my *getImageName* is called.
I changed my property i .h file to be *nonatomic, copy* and it did not help.

Comment: Did you also change in the call to `objc_setAssociatedObject`? In my test code I use a `char` rather than a pointer as the memory address, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those changes made it work. Could it be the reason of this is that it is done in a static library linked to the project?